# Objects of a sentence

Tags: grammar

I have a sentence which contains two objects, first of which is a noun, and second of which is a noun clause. Is this possible ?

> The human race always needs something beneficial to survive and
>   maintain its life. The reason for such a necessity is **the obstacles
>   the humankind is encountered by** and **the fact that the people are
>   vulnerable to life conditions.**

If it is grammatically wrong, how can I specify the statement ?

Comment: May I suggest you try and reformulate your sentence with your two ideas: "obstacles encountered by humankind" + "human vulnerability to living conditions". [maintain life, not its life]

Comment: "The obstacles the humankind is encountered by" makes no sense. What is the intended complement of "by"? What are you trying to say here?

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is possible to have a noun and a noun phrase be objects of the same verb or preposition.

**He admired the statue and the portrait being hung on the wall.**

However the passage quoted contains errors in grammar and usage that are unrelated to the question asked. I cannot straighten those out with certainty because I am not sure what the intended meaning is.

I think the first sentence is trying to say something like:

**Some things are necessary for human survival.**

I have no idea whatsoever how the second sentence is intended to clarify or expand upon the first if indeed I have deduced the meaning of the first.